# Cakephp 3 searching a plugin or a solution to read keyword into pdf file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm looking for a solution to use on cakephp, I have a directory that contains pdf files, inside my webapp I need to implement a search input, which takes care of finding the file that contains a certain keyword, but I haven't been able to find solutions. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but could not find anything suitable.
We ended up storing the PDF in Google Drive in a dedicated account and use Google APi to do the search.
Obviously it works only if the documents have no sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my case the documents have sensitive data, maybe i found a solution, if this will work, i will post it here in order to be useful for every other peoples.

Comment: No problem. We also considered to use Nextcloud, hosted in a private server, but it was a bit complicated to implement the a full text search inside the PDFs.